# Magneto lifting and throwing humans?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

Can Magneto lift and throw humans like Darth Vader can with Force powers? And did Magneto do it in the comics?

Answer (score 10):

His powers only deal with magnetic fields and related subjects (eg: electricity).

If a person is wearing enough iron, or objects with enough iron in them, he could lift them - and possibly control them, but the average person does not. A soldier, on the other hand, might have enough armor that might make them susceptible to body control by Magneto.

The closest thing I can think of for Magneto doing such things in the comics is when he ripped the adamantium from Wolverine's skeleton. I admit, though, that I haven't read all of the X-Men comics and none of them from the past 10 years, so it's certainly within the realm of possibility that he has controlled humans by controlling their clothes/armor.

In the second X-Men movie, Magneto rips out the iron which Mystique had injected into a guard. He could have used it to sort of puppet the guard had he wished. He also used his powers to control Wolverine in the first movie.

Comment: Armor? Considering Magneto is in 20th century, the armor is made of Kevlar, synthetic weave, ceramic plates, or at most, nanoceramics. None of the materials used to make armor in 20th century are even remotely magnetic.

Comment: I Believe that was actually the second movie.

Comment: @DVK, except in the savage land :p. But yes, that's why it's very unlikely but it IS possible.

Comment: @Kevin, you're correct. I edited my answer above to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

You're all wrong. Magneto can levitate people because water is diamagnetic. With a strong enough magnetic field, scientists have levitated animals like frog. Since magneto has ridiculous amounts of electromagnetism, he can lift a human without any iron content. He only needs water in the human body.

Answer (score 2):

Ferrous metals make up less than 1% of the body's mineral content – as opposed to Magneto's physical makeup, which has ten times the average human's iron content, according to the X-Men Unlimited series.

That would be enough for Magneto to manipulate various push and pull maneuvers, and could conceivably lift a person, but not without inflicting serious internal damage to the individual.

In Wolverine's case (as well as Deathstrike, Bullseye, Hammerhead, and some others), the adamantium in his body contains enough additional iron content that Magneto could levitate him without injuring his vital organs.

Comment: Iron in your blood is not ferromagnetic, as it is part of molecules, (for example, oxids) and does not form a crystal structure.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading that when asteroid M crashed to the earth, passing through the atmosphere greatly enhanced Magneto's powers. He was able to manipulate even the small traces of iron in a person's blood. This was also what made him powerful enough to separate the Adamantium from Wolverine's skeleton. Magneto was so power hungry at this point that Charles felt the only option was to make him a vegetable. Of course this [had its own side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X#Onslaught) In the Ultimate universe, I don't think any of this happened yet. But at his peak Magneto's powers were off the charts.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want my answer, its going to be a bit sarcastic, but pardon that.
He can do it if they have braces, otherwise use prostheses(including the various metal plates that doctors like putting in people's skulls after injury).
Of course these plates are usually not ferromagnetic, but even they can be affected by magnetic induction(a man with a titanium plate in his head cannot go into an MRI because it would become incredibly hot).
Of course, if Magneto has succeeded in gaining generic artifact of power enhancement, he might be able to pull the iron in blood(while simultaneously repelling hydrogen)...
Unfortunately all of these methods will harm the person, the latter causing them to explode, so don't get your hopes up for seeing it in a movie.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the comics, since I don't know them, but [this scene that shows Magneto escaping](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etPXBm0zRvM) shows that he can indeed lift up people (if they have a lot of iron in their blood, apparently).

Answer (score 1):

Protons, neutrons and electrons all have magnetic fields that interact to hold the atom together, the positive charges of the protons governing the number of negatively charged electrons orbiting the nucleus and therefore dictating the type of atom it is. The exchange of the negatively charged electrons between the positively charged nuclei of atoms is what creates molecules. These magnetic fields seem minuscule, but their combined strength is so strong that they overcome the forces of gravity. Hence the reason you do not simply fall through the ground into the center of the earth. The electromagnetic bonds between the atoms of you feet are repelled by the electromagnetic bonds of the atoms of the ground. These small magnetic fields cause a non-ferrous substance to be either paramagnetic or diamagnetic.
in other words yes he should be able to lift a human simply by controlling the electromagnetic bonds in the human body

Comment: This may be so but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes it does answer the question. everyone has a magnetic field in there body therefore he should be able to control that field and throw humans without metal.