# How is Magneto pulling Mystique in the Days of Future Past trailer?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, magneto

As seen in this screencap, Magneto seems to be pulling Mystique towards him using his powers. What I don't understand is, **how** can Magneto affect Mystique? Since when did he gain the ability to manipulate human beings using his powers? Or is there anything unique about Mystique that makes her vulnerable to this? Any comic references to this?
[image: Magneto pulling Mystique]

Comment: The iron in her blood...

Comment: Is there any reason it would be higher than any ordinary human being? We see in X-men 2 that she injects the security guard with loads of iron to let Magneto affect him. I don't really believe Magneto can manipulate blood iron. It is not seen even once anywhere else. The only one he has been able to manipulate, is Wolvering, which is pretty obvious.

Comment: Her magnetic personality?

Comment: @DVK  '-_- Something funnier perhaps? :P

Comment: Quick, somebody start a new question on the Biology SE: "how many steaks do you have to eat to have enough iron in your blood to where Magneto can..."

Comment: Possibly related, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12869/magneto-lifting-and-throwing-humans

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I went through the question. It does give some interesting answers, but still, doesn't answer anything very clearly. And I am more curious about this specific instance because in the entire X-men film series atleast, he has never been shown to be able to manipulate human bodies with the exception of the guard in X2, which had it's own reasons.

Comment: Even after watching the movie I'm still not so convinced. I feel Magneto's pull would pull out the bullet rather than drag the body with it... '-_-

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Spoiler alert**

After watching the film,

> Magneto shot her in the leg and is pulling the bullet towards him;
>  hence Mystique is being pulled as well. That is why in your screenshot, her leg is lifted a little.
> After he had brought her close enough, he pulled the bullet out of her leg.

For those of you wanting the answer but with less spoilers (spoiler tag anyway)

> Metal object inside Mystiques leg which Magneto is pulling towards him, thus the lifted leg in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks... The movie hadn't launched in my country when you posted the answer. I went and saw it later..

Comment: Awwh yeah I called being pulled by the leg.

Comment: This is why she's clutching her leg in pain. Seemed pretty clear to me! :)

Comment: In my opinion, the pulling force exerted over the bullet would make it come out of her leg. It's not clearly possible to drag her with the bullet inside.

Answer (score 9):

**For clarity the answer below is a pre-release trailer based answer**

There are many possible answers to this question you will not find out for certain until you watch the film.

1. Something she is wearing, he is not pulling her but pulling something she has on.
2. Like stated in the comments it's the iron in her blood that he is pulling.
3. She is holding onto something that he wants and he is dragging her as a result.

> how can Magneto affect Mystique? Since when did he gain the ability to manipulate human beings using his powers?

He can't affect her directly, he would have had this power in the future if he had gained it in the past. He still only has the power to influence metal in the future though.

> Or is there anything unique about Mystique that makes her vulnerable to this?

I doubt it, there has never been anything mentioned about Mystiques powers other than her transformations.

> Any comic references to this?

Not that I can recall although I'm not one of the more prominent comic aficionados of the site.

After re-watching the trailer it looks more and more like there is something on her ankle just due to the way in which her leg is raised, she is also clearly not holding anything.

Comment: She doesn't seem to be carrying anything. Even the ankle seems pretty normal. And Mystique doesn't really "wear" anything, so point 1 is pretty much moot here. And as per the movie series atleast, Magneto is not capable of pulling individuals just by the iron in their blood. The iron would come out clean. Was Magneto more powereful in the past?

Comment: @ash_k29 He was less powerful for instance in The first class movie we see his struggles to gain power where as in The last stand we see him easily move and snap the golden gate bridge.

Comment: But we see him lifting an entire stadium in the trailer. I guess that would mean he was pretty powerful at the time. But I don't think that would in any way grant him the ability to pull humans.

Comment: @ash_k29 We do indeed, and I would say he is indeed powerful at the time. Nothing suggests an ability that would be able to move humans. The fact is there must be metal of some form on or in Mystique.

Comment: It seems so. But nothing clear so far....

Comment: I'm betting it's 1.  The way she's curled up looks like handcuffs.

Comment: @Izkata If you watch the trailer her hands are scrambling on the floor and her leg and foot is pointing towards Magneto. The rest of her limbs are used in aid to resist the pull leading me to think there is something on her leg.

Comment: @Simon Soo, [ankle-cuffs](http://www.leelofland.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/New-Picture-110.jpg) perhaps.  That position in the screenshot could indeed also be her trying to get them off..

Comment: @Izkata Steel wool leg warmers I think.

Comment: @Simon Her arms seem pretty clearly pinned behind her; yeah, she's scrabbling to try and resist being pulled toward Magneto, but if she had her arms free you can bet that they'd be above her or out to her side and she'd be reaching for anything to hold on to, not keeping them behind her. I'm completely convinced she's in handcuffs, but of course we won't be able to settle this for certain until the movie is released (or another trailer reveals more of that scene).

Comment: @Kromey In the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK2zYHWDZKo#t=111 it shows her from behind looking as if her arms are tied round the front but from the front we see her arms scrabbling on the floor.

Comment: @Simon No, it really doesn't. Look at the way her shoulders are pulled back -- that's a clear indication that her arms are held behind her, not in front. (Don't ask how I know that.) I think I see what you're looking at, though, and while it can be confusing with her all-blue skin what you see above her shoulder just past her right cheek in that shot is, in fact, her breast, not her arm. This becomes self-evident if you watch it frame-by-frame as the shot transitions to looking at her from the front, where you can see her arms are behind her, yet it's evident she's in the same position.

Comment: @Kromey http://imgur.com/trgCEE3 How is that a breast?

Comment: @Simon That's clearly an arm, but a) that's not the shot from behind, and b) that's not past her right cheek, so that's clearly not what I was referencing. That arm is, however, behind her back, in a position that is fully compatible with the handcuffs theory.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that he has lifted human beings in the comics since his post-Asteroid M power-up, and also as a way for the comic writers to reference [diamagnetic levitation](http://www.physics.org/facts/frog-really.asp). Basically, the right magnetic field causes objects with a high water content to become briefly magnetic and thus able to be repelled or attracted.

It's a little ambiguous, since it's possible that he's working with the metal the soldiers presumably have somewhere on their body, but the following image's art (from the [Comic Book Legends Revealed site](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2009/08/13/comic-book-legends-revealed-220/)) suggests that he's moving the soldiers directly.
[image: Magneto casually repels and corrals soldiers using magnetism.]

Comment: This sounds very plausible, but  it hasn't been shown or referenced before... Atleast in the movie series for sure. But if we consider that, he could manipulate probably anyone!

Comment: Albeit with more effort. If you read up on the frog levitation experiments, it requires very strong and precise magnetic fields, and frogs are picked because they're particularly full of water. They say human beings might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: I don't suppose someone could comment on their downvote... do you feel that I provided inadequate information?

Comment: I certainly didn't. I feel the information was pretty accurate..

Comment: @ash_k29:
Ah, I'm mainly feeling a bit peeved. :) It's one downvote, more or less. And there is someone who came in later with an actual canonical answer based on the movie.

Answer (score 2):

She had been shot before. The bullet in her leg is his 'leverage'.

Comment: Might want to put a spoiler tag on that...

Comment: You're right, but this offers nothing new or more insightful than the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

He's the master of magnitism. It isn't limited to metal objects - he doesn't need any metal around his body to fly. He uses magnetic force fields to manipulate things, he can rip a large tree out of the ground, and launch it miles away. The movies have so much good material to work with out of the comic books; from astral projection, lightning manipulation, magnetic force fields, repulsor beams, all kinds of good stuff.

Comment: While it's a bit breathless of an answer, and you should provide citations for the trees and for him flying himself, this is more or less true, indicating the sheer breadth of the abilities he's shown, which would fit in with him being able to do this feat.

Comment: Can you provide a link to some scientific paper that reveals magnetic properties now apply to non-metallic materials? It would be fairly groundbreaking and you could become quite famous!